# Как перенести значения в несколько отдельных элементов?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть div контейнер, в котором находится произвольное количество div с текстом. Нужно сделать, чтобы при клике на контейнер значения всех внутренних div подставлялись в отдельные дивы за пределами контейнера. Как это сделать на JQuery? У меня почему-то содержимое всех div вставляется в один общий, либо несколько раз выводится значения последнего div

Получиться должно примерно следующее:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div>Красный</div>
   <div>Желтый</div>
   <div>Зеленый</div>
</div>

<div class='result'>Красный</div>
<div class='result'>Желтый</div>
<div class='result'>Зеленый</div>
```

Comment: Вы пишете, что ваше решение работает не так, как нужно. Можете показать его?

Comment: $('.container').each(function () {
    $('.result').text($(this).text());
});

Comment: Прочитайте о селекторах в jquery

Comment: $('.container > div').each(function () { $('.result').text($(this).text()); }); Так только последнее значение несколько раз выводится

Answer (score 0):

Вот как вы должны были написать. Но чтобы понять что не так с вашим кодом, вы должны понять как работают 
css селекторы: [https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Селекторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

```js
$('.container_el').each(function (index, el){
  let text = $(el).text();
  $('#result').append(`<div>${text}</div>`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="container_el">1</div>
  <div class="container_el">2</div>
  <div class="container_el">3</div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: append() создает новые экземпляры div при новых кликах, а не заменяет текущие значения

Comment: @Семен попробуйте доработать мой код так, как это вам необходимо